# j_security_check not found error coming when tring to login again

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, jaas, j-security-check

Using form-based authentication with `j_security_check`.

- The first logon works.
- User presses back button.
- The second logon fails.
- The browser URL after the second logon fails is `http://(mydomain/j_security_check`.

"404 Not Found" is the error message printed on the page.

Can someone please shed some light on this issue? I'd like to at least be able to redirect if this happens so the user doesn't see the 404.

**More explanation:**

The issue is not starting a session. The session starts after the first logon like it should. The problem occurs, if the user decides to press the back button after logging in. This should not happen but it does. Once the user presses back, they are back on the log in page. If they try to log in again on that page, they end up at the url `http://(mydomain)/j_security_check` and receive a 404 error. The user is very confused and thinks the web app is busted. I'm looking for a way to redirect them if they end up at that url `http://(mydomain)/j_security_check`. I am using Java Server Faces. Is that enough information? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mixing JSF2 and Struts2 ?

Comment: Why not check if a user is logged in then the login page should redirect him in your application's main page else display the login component?

Comment: Are you using jboss? I encountered this error in jboss7 and it was a known bug back then.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no :) . Still have the same issue